# Wowza + Live Streaming + Windows Phones?

Tags: windows-phone-8, rtmp, live-streaming, smooth-streaming

I'm newbie in Live Streaming logics but I now have a Wowza backended setup and i got following streams out from server:

```
http://.................../mychannel/playlist.m3u8
http://.................../mychannel/Manifest
rtmp://.................../mychannel&streamType=live
rtsp://.................../mychannel
```

So lets say for `iOS`, i simply put:

```
<video x-webkit-airplay="allow" type="video/m3u8" controls src="http://........../mychannel/playlist.m3u8" />
```

For `Desktop/ Flash` Playbacks:

```
<object>
 <param name="movie" value="http://fpdownload.adobe.com/strobe/FlashMediaPlayback.swf"></param>
 <param name="flashvars" value="src=rtmp://................/mychannel&streamType=live"></param>
 <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param>
 <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param>
 <embed src="http://fpdownload.adobe.com/strobe/FlashMediaPlayback.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="640" height="360" flashvars="src=rtmp://.............mychannel&streamType=live"></embed>
</object>
```

Then for `Android` direct streaming:

```
<a href="rtsp://............/mychannel">Play</a>
```

So now the BIG QUESTION comes!
The only 1 thing i just want to know is:

- How can i make (any of) above **Streams to BE PLAYABLE on WINDOWS PHONES** simply?
- SIMPLY means, as like above ones, i can just simply hard-code inside my HTML page!

*(I totally DO NOT know about Windows & its programmings/ sdks/ as well)*

Answer (score 0):

Windows Phones don't have a well support/players by default for live streaming.
Microsoft's official streaming protocol is Smooth Streaming and wowza support this. But Windows Phones need custom player to play Smooth Streaming.
If you want use a simple method, you can embed a mms link in a web page. Windows phones play mms streams by default. But you need windows media services for mms streaming wowza doesn't support it.

Comment: There's a new release of the VLC player for Windows Phone out now.

Answer (score 0):

I think until now on windows phone 8.1 https://github.com/mntone/RtmpClient can help you.